# white black screen while loading unity in android for 2-5 seconds

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I use android for launching unity activity. First a white then black screen and then my splash screen came after launching unity activity. But after changing the manifest file I am able to remove the black screen but the black screen still appears for 2-5 seconds. How can I get rid of that too?

Comment: Hey please can show me the gradle and the manifest

Comment: my manifest file: <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Game" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:process="com.AlgorinTechlabs.bricks.game" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection" android:name="com.AlgorinTechlabs.bricks.UnityPlayerActivity">

Comment: theme file:<style name="Game" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/some_image</item>
</style>

Comment: in gradle file which part would you like to see since i haven't change anything